# How to optimize spark sql select queries with filter on non partition columns?

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, partitioning

We have a spark table which is partitioned on, say Column A, Column B.
This table also has a Timestamp column, like "Last Modified At"

In Our pipelines which process data, we want to pick up only the data that changed after the last pipeline run an hour ago. Hence, we do a query like -

```
select * from Table where TimestampColumn > '<timestamp one hour ago>'
```

This filter takes a lot of time because the filtered column is not part of the partition columns.
How do we optimize this?

Comment: What is the source of `Table` and are you able to partition it by hour? As that would then open up the potential for Spark predicate push down to only read the necessary partitions (depending on the input source type).